# Is there a different way to draw on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, drawing

So, I have been having trouble drawing multiple objects on a JFrame, and I know I need to use Layout managers, so I decided to test it with one object before I do multiple, however when I run this code:

```
        fps = 30;

        panel = new JPanel();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.addKeyListener(new key());

        running = true;
        update = true;

        ball = new Ball(0,0,1);

        //panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.add(ball);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

nothing draws (There is more to the code, i just didnt want to inlcude all of it). However, when I remove the comment and set the background to black, the JFrame turns black. So why is it that it wont draw my Ball object (which i know works) but will change the background? Is there a specific way you need to draw on a JPanel?

Comment: Write your own class extends JPanel, override the paint method (which passes a Graphics object) and use that to render stuff.

Comment: It would be great if you can share a minimal testable code. We don't know what are you doing in `Ball` class?

Comment: as it is, there's nothing drawing in it. What does `Ball` class contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> panel = new JPanel();

By default a JPanel uses a `FlowLayout` which respects the size of any component you add to the panel.

> ball = new Ball(0,0,1);

I have no idea what the code in your Ball class looks like, but I would guess the preferred size is (0, 0).

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your Ball class to return the size of the Ball so that your layout manager can do its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

> I know I need to use Layout managers,

The problem with a layout manager in this case is that the layout manager will control the position of the Ball which may or may not be what you want. If you want balls in random positions, then you will need to use a null layout. Then you will need to use the setSize() and setLocation()  methods to control each Ball component.

Another option is to do custom painting of all your Balls. In this case you would add an object that you want to paint to an ArrayList. Then the custom painting code would iterate through the object in the list and paint them individually. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for ideas on this approach.